# ASP.NET MVC RavenDB Save User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I know how to save documents to the RavenDB but i'm trying to look in to how I can save a User object:

```
public class User
{
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Sure, I can save an object of User but, what about Password encryption? And is there a "proper" or a different way of saving a User object? Saving and Retrieving a User object is my whole goal.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Password encryption you'd have to implement yourself. See an example here:

https://github.com/synhershko/NSemble/blob/master/NSemble.Web/Modules/Welcome/WelcomeModule.cs
https://github.com/synhershko/NSemble/blob/master/NSemble.Core/Nancy/NSembleUserAuthentication.cs

The User object is not different than any other object in your system.